# Newly created javascript object property cannot be accessed elsewhere in the code. I receive "Property does not exist on type" error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

```js
// New javascript objects**

let askNow = {
  findingID: 234,
  findingName: 'Vulnerabilities',
};

let shiftLeft = {
  findingID: 456,
  findingName: 'shiftVulnerabiities',
};

// Storing javascript objects in an array**

let sources = [askNow, shiftLeft];

// Adding new property**

const addNewProperty = function(src) {
  src.forEach(function(srcs) {
    srcs.findingStatus = 'open';
  });
};
addNewProperty(sources);
console.log(sources);

// Error in Accessing the new property elsewhere**

const index = sources.findIndex(function(cur, i, arr) {
  console.log(cur.findingStatus);
})
```

Comment: Why do you think it's having a problem accessing the property? It logs `open`.

Comment: The error appears in the last line where I try to do console.log (cur.findingStatus). When I hover over the visual studio code, the error states "Property findingStatus does not exist on type. However when I console log the sources array, It does display the newly created property in both the objects. What seem to be the problem here?

Comment: There's no error when I run it here.

Comment: That's a VSCode warning, not from JavaScript. It doesn't know that the property was added in the `addNewProperty()`, it just knows the properties that were in the literals.

Comment: Add the property with a default value in the literals and VSCode will know about it.

Comment: It does log "open". I am trying to understand the text that I get when I hover over the code . It states "Property findingStatus does not exist on type". This might be a problem when using in conditional statement such as an "If block".

Comment: I added the defaultValue as suggested in the objects. The warning went away now. Thank you. This helped.

Comment: How do you expect an editor to know that the function will modify those objects?

Comment: Understood! Thank you very much. This got resolved by using default values.

Comment: @ShilpaC, "type error", possible your visual studio code have some plugins who detect this.

In JavaScript when you create some object and assign it value, by default it type has been decided to the same.

After that, you are adding some other key which is not there at the time of initialization, so it is showing you that "type" error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.